# How to asynchronous run http requests in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio

this code  i'm running synchronously

```
import requests 
  
URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
  
location = "delhi technological university"
  
PARAMS = {'address':location} 
  

for _ in range(1,100):
    r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS) 
    print(r)
```

how to run the same code asynchronously using python

tried this:

```
import requests
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
  
location = "delhi technological university"
  
PARAMS = {'address':location} 


async def run():
    for j in range(1,100):
        
        r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
    loop.close()
```

tried the above code but getting run time error . RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Comment: How are you running they code? Some environments have a loop running already and that would lead to that error. Once you address that, however, your code still won't really be asynchronous. Your first problem is that requests isn't asyncio-aware. You'll need to use a different library such as aiohttp. Then you'll need to refactor the code because awaiting inside a loop blocks iteration until the call returns. You'll need to use something like `asyncio.gather` to allow additional calls to be made at the same time.

Comment: can you share any doc